# Prevent source code stealing from Jenkins

Tags: continuous-integration

I know Jenkins is a good solution for CI. I think yes we can use it on our solutions. I can install Jenkins services to the client side servers and we will be free for publishment and version control tracking.

**But i couldn't understand that How would i prevent source code stealing from remote machines?**

So Jenkins directly connected to Github and it downloads all solution source codes to the remote machines. My all source codes will inside of my client side. And somebody can easy take all source codes who has admin or read rights for the disk.. And my all solution was gone..

I couldn't find answer for this. How CI could be best practice. I guess They dont install Jenkins or CI services to the client side. Otherwise all source codes would be stolen.

Could you explain? What is the design of CI services between client side? It must be only in our machines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually - you cannot.

generally speaking: if you upload your code to third-party server - it's could be downloaded 'third-party' persons. :)

Comment: So, big companies doesn't install jenkins or CI services to client side? Its only inside of software company. They are just publish compiled codes?

Comment: Big companies (or even mid/small companies) create internal infrastructure: with own Version control server, CI/CD server etc.

And, you right - publish just compiled code (appstore,gplay etc), or allow access to it (http)